# Loop through collection of web service result

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, wsdl

I am using a web reference to acces some public data (http://portalquery.just.ro/query.asmx). 
I have added in a project in visual studio the web reference and named it "just.ro".  I am not familiar with this kind of query and I didn't find any resource explaining how to manipulate the data.

This web reference is a query and it returns a collection of elements named `ret`. Each `ret` element has a single `obiect` sub-element and multiple `sedinte` elements. Each `sedinte` element has `SolutieSumar` and `DocumentSedinta` elements.

The code I have written so far is:

```
 just.ro.Query ws = new just.ro.Query();
            just.ro.Dosar[] ret = ws.CautareDosare(TextBox1.Text, null, null, just.ro.Institutie.JudecatoriaALBAIULIA, null, null);
            if (ret != null)
            {
                TextBox2.Text = ret.FirstOrDefault().obiect.ToString();
...
                 TextBox7.Text = ret.FirstOrDefault().sedinte.FirstOrDefault().solutieSumar.ToString();
                 TextBox8.Text = ret.FirstOrDefault().sedinte.FirstOrDefault().documentSedinta.ToString();
             }
```

What I want is to loop through all `sedinte` collection from `ret.FirstOrDefault()` result and display in a textbox the `solutieSumar` string of the element of the collection in which `documentSedinta` is a string named "Hotarare". There is only one such element in the `sedinte` collection.

Basically, I want to find an approach for looping to a collection from a web reference result.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't working doing like this: foreach(var item in ret.FirstOrDefault().sedinte){TextBox7.Text=item.solutieSumar.ToString();}?

Comment: I've used your code first and then I've put an if condition for the prefered output. `var tipdocument = item.documentSedinta.ToString();                     if (tipdocument.Contains("Hotarare")) {                     TextBox9.Text = item.solutieSumar.ToString();            }}`

Comment: So it worked, I have posted it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through the List, as:

```
foreach(var item in ret.FirstOrDefault().sedinte)
{
  TextBox7.Text=item.solutieSumar.ToString();
}
```